# Automatically correct Lingua::LinkParser include lib path

Tags: perl, ubuntu, makefile, cpan, linkparser

I'm building a script that will run on an EC2 instance that will automatically install our required packages and modules.
I'm having an issue with Perl module `Lingua::LinkParser`.
During compile it complains

```
LinkParser.xs:5:27: error: link-includes.h: No such file or directory
```

On Ubuntu link-includes.h is provided by package `link-grammar` and is installed in /usr/include/link-grammar/.
However Lingua::LinkParser's Makefile.PL is hard-coded(?) to look in /usr/local/include/link-grammar/.

Is there simple-ish way to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'd submit a bug to the module's author about the hardcoded path

Comment: Filing a bug is definitely a good thing, however I have no idea how long it will take for them to release a fix(if at all). I wouldn't want to delay this project so I'd like to find a solution that would work with the current package's state.

Comment: Can't you just make a symbolic link from `/usr/include/link-grammar` to `/usr/local/include/link-grammar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mob's suggestion above to just symlink /usr/include/link-grammar to /usr/local/include/link-grammar is the simplest way of handling this situation and this is what I'll use.

Answer (score 2):

[Distroprefs](http://p3rl.org/CPAN#Configuration-for-individual-distributions-Distroprefs-)

- [Best practice for using slightly modifying module from CPAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663412/best-practice-for-using-slightly-modifying-module-from-cpan)
- [Install Perl modules that require customized options via CPAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237583/install-perl-modules-that-require-customized-options-via-cpan)

Comment: Hmm, perhaps this is the most proper way of doing it, but (at least to me) seems pretty involved. I'll have to read up on this to see how feasible it is to do in our current setup and if that will allow me to override that hardcoded path